# Prevent Page from complete refresh while passing data from ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I am trying to submit simple form on the header php file and accessing its value to change the content of the page in one of my views. I am able to pass the ajax value but when I do that complete header page get reloaded again. Please help me how to prevent the reload of the page.

**Here is my form in the header file**

```
<form  class="choose-form form-holder" >
                                <select id="usertype" onChange="selectChange()">
                                    <option value=1>JS</option>
                                    <option value=2>JP</option>
                                </select>
</form>
```

**Here is my Script to submit the form in the php header file**

```
<script>
function selectChange() {
            debugger;
            var usertype = $('#usertype').val();
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'GET',
                    data: {usertype: usertype},
                    success: function (response) {                  
                        $('#response').html(response);
                    },
                    error: function () {
                        alert("error");
                    }
                });
                return false;
        }
</script>
```

This is my code in php view page to access the type and change the content

```
<div id="response">
        <?php if(!empty($_GET['usertype'])){
            $type = $_GET['usertype'];

        }
?></div>

<?php if ((isset($type)) && ($type == 2)){?>
            //some other content
<?php }else{  ?>
    //change the content
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Where is your AJAX pointed to? I don't see any targeted file.

Comment: I have not passed url as I want to get data on the same page

Comment: So what you're doing here is that on select you check what they selected and display the appropriate content based on that? Then you don't need ajax since this can all be done using JS

Comment: Sure, thanks so much for the suggestion! Can you please help me how can I pass via JS and check in my if else condition? I am sorry but I am very new to this and learning it.

Comment: Please add the "jquery" tag.

Comment: Where should I add please? in my selectChange function.

Answer (score -1):

Try below:

```
<script>
function selectChange(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    debugger;
    var usertype = $('#usertype').val();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        data: {usertype: usertype},
        success: function (response) {
            $('#response').html(response);
        },
        error: function () {
            alert("error");
        }
    });
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Sibusiso. I tried this. Its giving me "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'preventDefault' of undefined" error. Do  I need to add something more here please?